# What are the possible security issues (breach/losing access) with sharing passwords manually?

Tags: password-management

I am thinking of forming a team in either LastPass or 1Password.

LastPass is free if I don't intend to use it to share my passwords.

I am wondering, why would I need to form a team?

If I want to share a password with my buddy I can just type the password in Skype and he can insert that password to his password manager. Why need the complexity of "teams" and "families"?

Complexity is a factor. If I misunderstand a feature, things can go really really wrong

Such as this https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/96592/can-i-share-passwords-without-team-or-family#latest

Is it worth the trouble to share password via password managers' share feature?

The only benefit I can think of is that changing a password is "propagated" to my buddies.

However, most of our passwords are not shared and we share only at most 10 passwords with each other.

Comment: Please review the vendor's description of benefits of the Teams/Family feature.

Comment: it makes it far easier to manage team's password's centrally and instantly than having them all cut and pasting around messengers windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing a password is always a problem because you never know where it is going to end up. For example, if you send it by email, it might end up in the backups of the hosting provider, in the email client of whoever you sent it to, etc. Not to mention that apparently email can still be sent in the clear (not encrypted) from one server to another, or at least so I learned. As for Skype for example, the password might remain in the chat history, either on the user's device or on Microsoft's servers.

Apparently (or so I learned) an acceptable way to share a password is to use separate channels to send the information. For example, you might encrypt it, and send it encrypted via email, and then tell the password for decryption in a phone call. Or send a piece of the password via SMS, and the rest in a phone call. This way it's going to be harder for an attacker to intercept the password or recover it.

As you see all this can get pretty complicated (and a pain in the neck). LastPass and other online password managers then can make your life easier for this task, by allowing users to share some passwords with other accounts.

Comment: I can verbally tell my friend that I am sending password via whatsapp. At whatsapp I send the password. Any hacker that got the password will not know whawt website uses that password. Especially if the password looks like 348dgfl34$&#!

Comment: But good answer nevertheless.